# Chrome Extensions: Eventlisten on current tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, tabs, event-handling

I've made an extension with `page_action`, unfortunately I can't use `browser_action` too, so I need to rewrite my code for `browser_action`.

I'm checking the URL of a tab and when it's matched with RegExp, the icon changes. This works, but only if a tab gets reloaded or created, but not when i'm just visit different, already loaded tabs. So the icon doesn't change, even if the URL is totally "wrong".

Just the old code:

```
function checkHosts(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    if(hosts.length>0)
        if(hosts.some(function (element, index, array) { return RegExp("(http|ftp|https)://([\w\.]*)"+element+"(.*)/").test(tab.url)})) {
            chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path: 'img/icon-19.png'})
        } else {
            chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path: 'img/icon-19_off.png'})
        }
}

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(checkHosts);
```

So I tried to change the Event from `onUpdated` to `onActivated`. It gives me this error (brace yourself):

```
Error in event handler for tabs.onActivated: TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined
at chrome-extension://hjldlodngamjdnompiekojgebnmolnab/background.js:28:122
at Array.some (native)
at checkHosts (chrome-extension://hjldlodngamjdnompiekojgebnmolnab/background.js:28:12)
at Function.target.(anonymous function) (extensions::SafeBuiltins:19:14)
at Event.dispatchToListener (event_bindings:382:22)
at Event.dispatch_ (event_bindings:367:27)
at dispatchArgs (event_bindings:241:26)
at dispatchEvent (event_bindings:250:7)
```

I can't get the mistake I did, so it would be really nice if someone could help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The signature of the callback function for `onActivated` is different from the one for `onUpdated`.

Cf the [chrome.tabs API](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#event-onActivated) for the `onActivated` event handler:

> **Callback**
>
> The callback parameter should specify a function that looks like this:
>
> `function(object activeInfo) {...};`

That means that when your `checkHosts` method is called as the event handler, only the first argument is filled (it's the `activeInfo` object), and the other twos are undefined. Thus the error you receive.

To fix your issue, you'll have to change the signature of your method. Beware that the `activeInfo` object you'll receive doesn't have the new url of the tab.